# Using events in separated functions plus own variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying some stuff with HTML5 Multiupload. So I have a form and can load multiple files. They are read via FileApi and fileinformation is shown to the user.

Pseudo-code:

```
<div id="info">
   <div id="file_1">...</div>
   <div id="file_2">...</div>
   ...
</div>
```

So I process all files withing `$.each()`, and increment my `var fileId`.
For the upload itself I add EventListener to my XMLHTTPRequest

```
xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
```

But I wan't to remove the filecontainer `#file_X` when the upload is complete. So i could do this:

```
xhr.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {
   if(evt.target.readyState == 2 && evt.target.status == 200)
   {
       $('#file_' + fileId).slideUp();
   }
}
```

And my question is, can I separate this code in a function? It doesn't work that I send the event and the parameter to a separated function like this:

```
xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete(evt, fileId), false);
```

Is there a smarter way then doing this:

```
xhr.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {
   uploadComplete(evt, fileId);
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with the last way? That's how you do it... you could create some helper functions which lets you bind arguments, but eventually, this is doing the same.

Comment: Actually I did not get this solution until I write the post ;-) But the question is, if or how I can use `xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete(evt, fileId), false);` OR WHY this will not work. Thank you

Comment: It does not work because `uploadComplete` is executed immediately and the *return value* is passed to `addEventListener` as "event handler". This would work if `uploadComplete` returned a function, but if it doesn't you probably get an error. You always have to pass a *function reference* to `addEventListener`... putting `()` behind a function reference *calls* the function.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Sorry, I misread your question. I've updated my answer.

The script doesn't work because after the `$.each()` loop, `var fileId` will contain the value it was given on the last iteration of the loop. So if you have 10 files, `fileId` will be `"file_10"` for the rest of the script (which is not what you want).

Instead of a reference to `var fileId`, you want to pass your event handler the *current* value. Luckily, you can do just that by creating a closure:

```
$('#info').each(function(){
    /* Do your thing, start the XHR and whatnot */

    (function(currentFileId) {
        xhr.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {
            uploadComplete(evt, currentFileId);
        });
    }) (fileId);
});
```

You can read more about closures in any good JavaScript book or on the internet, e.g. [here (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

I hope this helps.